# Appending data to an empty dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am creating an empty dataframe and later trying to append another data frame to that. In fact I want to append many dataframes to the initially empty dataframe dynamically depending on number of RDDs coming.

the union() function works fine if I assign the value to another a third dataframe.

```
val df3=df1.union(df2)
```

But I want to keep appending to the initial dataframe (empty) I created because I want to store all the RDDs in one dataframe. The below code however does not show right counts. It seems that it simply did not append

```
df1.union(df2)

df1.count() // this shows 0 although df2 has some data and that is shown if I assign to third datafram.
```

If I do the below (I get reassignment error since df1 is val. And if I change it to var type, I get kafka multithreading not safe error.

```
df1=d1.union(df2)
```

Any idea how to add all the dynamically created dataframes to one initially created data frame?

Comment: the transformation that you applied by doing union is not saved. and to save you have to do assignment. thats how you save the transformation in dataframes and I suggest you to look at foldLeft option for the kind of union you require

Comment: Ramesh is right about assignment.  I might also advise against union of dataframes with different schemas. Spark do not merge schemas at this stage and you will end up with data in wrong columns.

Comment: thanks but at the moment I am using same schema. can you please give me example of doing foldLeft in this case? appreciated.

Comment: Hi Omer, any transformation to the dataset creates a new dataframe so if you are not appending by chaining then it wont help you. Consider understanding dataframe and their immutability feature to avoid any confusions.

Comment: like @MichelLemay mentioned you need to take care of the schemas.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for!

```
# Import pyspark functions
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType 

# Define your schema
field = [StructField("Col1",StringType(), True), StructField("Col2", IntegerType(), True)]
schema = StructType(field)

# Your empty data frame
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)

l = []

for i in range(5):
    # Build and append to the list dynamically
    l = l + [([str(i), i])]

    # Create a temporary data frame similar to your original schema
    temp_df = spark.createDataFrame(l, schema)

    # Do the union with the original data frame
    df = df.union(temp_df)
df.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrames` and other distributed data structures are immutable, therefore methods which operate on them always return new object. There is no appending, no modification in place, and no `ALTER TABLE` equivalent.

> And if I change it to var type, I get kafka multithreading not safe error.

Without actual code is impossible to give you a definitive answer, but it is unlikely related to `union` code.

There is a number of known Spark bugs cause by incorrect internal implementation ([SPARK-19185](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19185), [SPARK-23623](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23623) to enumerate just a few).